# All child elements inheriting onclick event from parent div on React

Tags: reactjs, events

This is my code on return section. All children elements is ineriting click events and when I click it is giving me the object of that child element not parent.

```
return (
  <div className={css(style.cell)} onClick={this.props.onClickHandle}>

      <div className={css(style.image)}>
        <CircleImage size={50} url = {"http://www.ruralagriventures.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/man-team.jpg"}/>
      </div>

      <div className={css(style.info)}>

        <div className={css(style.profile)}>
          <span>{this.props.name}</span>
          <span className={css(style.lastMessage)}>Latest Message</span>
        </div>

        <div className={css(style.detail)}>
          <span>a few seconds ago</span>
          <span className={css(style.counter)}>5</span>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
)
```

I only want an object from parent div, not children. Before passing props
I assigned `this.onClickHandle = this.onClickHandle.bind(this);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `refs`, refer this [link](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

```
onClickHandle(e){
    this.parentDiv //parent object
}

return (
  <div ref={(parentDiv) => { this.parentDiv = parentDiv; }} className={css(style.cell)} onClick={this.props.onClickHandle}>

      <div className={css(style.image)}>
        <CircleImage size={50} url = {"http://www.ruralagriventures.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/man-team.jpg"}/>
      </div>

      <div className={css(style.info)}>

        <div className={css(style.profile)}>
          <span>{this.props.name}</span>
          <span className={css(style.lastMessage)}>Latest Message</span>
        </div>

        <div className={css(style.detail)}>
          <span>a few seconds ago</span>
          <span className={css(style.counter)}>5</span>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
)
```